# How do I control access rights on BigQuery dataset from command line?

Tags: google-bigquery

I see that it is possible to share dataset via [API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/datasets#access.userByEmail), but for some reason there is no option like that in `bq` or `gcloud`. Does I would have to go to UI or make an API call manually?